# How to make two colors in a progress bar dynamically for webapplication in silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, colors, progress-bar, c#-2.0

I am trying to develop c# web application using silverlight-5.

I have to create a progress bar which will have two colors green(up to some percentage) and then Red which will be done dynamically by some data manipulation in c#.

I want to make it of two colors by some percentage of green and rest red (percentage will be decided at run time). I read several documents but were complicated for me to understand.

Could someone please help me to write it's code in c# ? (Or if this progress bar don't change color by value taken at runtime then could some one please write a simple code to create a custom progress bar changing color at run time according to the changing values at run time). Would be a big help.Thanks

**Probably i guess the code will be written in c# because in xaml the colors display ratio will be fixed but it's percentage of these 2 colors has to change according to data values obtained at run time in c# code**

Note: I am developing webapplication using silverlight and c#.

so code has to be written in body like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace B
{
    public partial class MainPage : UserControl
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


    }
}
```

EDIT : I tried to do

progressBar.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0);

it gave me error "using System.Drawing.Color;" the Error is:The type or namespace name 'Drawing' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?

when i tried to add "using System.Drawing.Color; "

and there is no assembly i could found b name "System.Drawing.dll"

May be silverlight version problem or may be some other problem.

Could some one please help me changing the progress bar color change dynamically ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here you need to validate your progress bar value eg when its valu=80% then change color and to change color you need to do like this

```
progressBar.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0);
```

and you can change the color to any color.

Comment: @Terrbyte thanks but Error 1 'System.Windows.Controls.ProgressBar' does not contain a definition for 'ForeColor' and no extension method 'ForeColor' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Controls.ProgressBar' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: Add this name space using System.Drawing.Color;

Comment: sorry how to add that ? is it any assembly i need to add ? What is the name of assembly exactly to be added as reference?

Comment: On doing this "using System.Drawing.Color;" the Error is:The type or namespace name 'Drawing' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: And another thing there is no dll with this name when i try to add reference to it in my project.

Comment: check this site  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.forecolor(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: but i have nothing like "System.Drawing.dll" in my project when i try to add reference. Is it any version problem of silverlight or may be any other problem like this. I tried to manually download a "System.Drawing.dll" and tried to reference it in my project and the result was a messagebox showing "SILVERLIGHT only support silverlight asseblies....somthing like this". Please help me in making the solution.please..i am not able to solve it since yesterday

Comment: i also tried to do this "progressBar.Foreground = Color.FromArgb(255,0,0,255);" but it gives : Error :Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Windows.Media.Color' to 'System.Windows.Media.Brush (Forecolor actually don't exist in my project, i think it's foreground in my case)

Comment: Sorry this assembly is not meant for silverlight application so i guess tthis approach will not work.